# Weblogic cache cleanup while its Running

Tags: java, caching, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

Will a Weblogic keep running fine if we delete the /tmp or /cache folder while the Weblogic is already UP?
Issue is we accidently cleared the cache while JVMs were

Comment: As java is a dynamic language you could face issues with your applications. You should restart all your servers.